# Grok filters for the below log message

Tags: filter, logstash, grok

I am working on writing a pattern for  this specific line through GROK filter
"NOTIFICATION-Interface_IF-asdasdsf01.chn.asdfasp.com/1074_Down"
Can some one help me with this please .

This is the reg-ex i came up with
[A-Z]\w+[-][A-Z][a-z]\w+[*]\w+[a-zA-Z][-]\w+[a-zA-Z0-9][.][A-Za-z]\w+[.][A-Za-z]\w+[.][a-z]\w+/[0-9]\d+[*][A-Za-z]\w+

but i want it for "NOTIFICATION-Interface_IF-asdasdsf01.chn.asdfasp.com/1074_Down" as well as with out the chn in the hostname
NOTIFICATION-Interface_IF-asdasdsf01.asdfasp.com/1074_Down

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Which data would you capture ?

Using this kind of pattern if would be possible to capture multiple data

```
%{WORD:type}-%{WORD:interface}-%{GREEDYDATA:client}
```

Will be produce

```
type = "NOTIFICATION"
interface = "Interface_ID"
client = "asdasdsf01.chn.asdfasp.com/1074_Down"
```

Don't hesitate to test and upgrade the pattern using the [grok debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/). See [here](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns) the native patterns from logstash.

PS : your first regexp can be simplify : `([A-Z]+)\-([A-Za-z]+)_([A-Za-z]+)\-(.*)\/([0-9]+)_([A-Za-z]+)`. Depending of your delimiter, it can be more easy.
You can test is using this [link](https://regex101.com/r/dzqPV0/1)